# Collision Detection on 2 objects

Tags: javascript, collision

I have 2 cars on my canvas and i want it to stop when hitting another car. The code i put doesn't seem to work. I think there is a mistake on how i call the function with windowsaddevent listener but im not sure.

Here is My code for Collision Detection:

```
//=======================
//Car Collision Detection
//=======================

function carDetect() {
    var a = y - (car.height / 2)
    var b = y1 + (car1.height / 2) - 50;

    if (a <= b) {
    speed = 0;
    x -= 0;
    mod1 = 0;
    speed1 = 0;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", carDetect, true);
window.addEventListener("keyup", carDetect, true);
```

I can send all of the code if you want and if you have any question just comment and i will answer immediately

Thanks

Here is the rest of my code:

```
//Setting the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('background');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//================
//ENTER: USER CAR
//================

//Uploading car sprite
var car = new Image();
car.src = "img/Car.png";

//Setting properties of car
var x = 450;
var y = 730;
var speed = 10;
var angle = -90;
var mod = 0;

//Event listeners for keys
window.addEventListener("keydown", keypress_handler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup_handler, false);

//Interval for animation
var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
    draw();
}, 30);

//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    context.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
    context.restore();

    drawCar();
    drawCar2();
}

//Setting the keys
function keyup_handler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {

        mod = 0;
    }
}

//Setting all of the keys
function keypress_handler(event) {
    console.log(x, y);
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        x -= 20;

    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        x -= -20;
    }
}

//=====================
//ENTER: OBSTACLE CAR 1
//=====================

//Uploading car
var car1 = new Image();
car1.src = "img/Car.png";

//Setting properties of car
var x1 = 450;
var y1 = 40;
var speed1 = 5;
var angle1 = 90;
var mod1 = 1;

//Interval for animation
 var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
     drawCar();
 }, 300);

//Drawing the car turning and changing speed
function drawCar() {

          x1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
          y1 += (speed1 * mod1) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);

          context.save();
          context.translate(x1, y1);
          context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle1);
          context.drawImage(car1, -(car1.width / 1), -(car1.height / 1));
          context.restore();

          drawMultiple();
      drawElapsedTime();
          }        

function DrawTime() {
    if (drawElapsedTime == 2) {
         x2 += (speed2 * mod2) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);
          y2 += (speed2 * mod2) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);

          context.save();
          context.translate(x2, y2);
          context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);
          context.drawImage(car2, -(car2.width / 1), -(car2.height / 1));
          context.restore();

          drawMultiple2();
    }
}


//================================
//ENTER: OBSTACLE CAR 2 Properties
//================================

//Uploading car
var car2 = new Image();
car2.src = "img/Car.png";

//Setting properties of car
var x2 = 300;
var y2 = 30;
var speed2 = 5;
var angle2 = 90;
var mod2 = 1;

function drawCar2(){
        if (parseInt((new Date() - startTime) / 1000) >= 2) {
          x2 += (speed2 * mod2) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);
          y2 += (speed2 * mod2) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);

          context.save();
          context.translate(x2, y2);
          context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle2);
          context.drawImage(car2, -(car2.width / 1), -(car2.height / 1));
          context.restore();

          drawMultiple2();
    }
    }

//=========================
//Properties for score keep
//=========================
var score;
var theInterval = setInterval(gameStart, 200000);
var startTime;
startTime = new Date();


//===========================
//Draw Final and Elasped Time
//===========================
function drawElapsedTime() {
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.font = "30px Verdana"
        context.fillText(parseInt((new Date() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs", canvas.width - 150, 40);
        context.restore();
    }  

function drawFinalScore() {
        // set the final score just once
        if (score == null) {
            score = parseInt((new Date() - startTime) / 1000);
        }
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.font = "30px Verdana"
        context.fillText("Game Over: " + score + " secs", 50, 100);
        context.restore();
    }

//=======================
//Car Collision Detection
//=======================

function carDetect() {
    var a = y - (car.height / 2)
    var b = y1 + (car1.height / 2) - 50;

    if (a <= b) {
    speed = 0;
    x -= 0;
    mod1 = 0;
    speed1 = 0;
    clearInterval(theInterval);
        drawFinalScore();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", carDetect, true);
window.addEventListener("keyup", carDetect, true);


//=========================================================
//Draw Obstacle Cars from top to bottm at random positions
//=========================================================
function drawMultiple() {

    if (y1 > context.canvas.height + 150){

        y1 = -car1.height;
        x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 630);
        drawCar();
    }
};

//Draw the obstacle car from top to bottom
function drawMultiple2() {

    if (y2 > context.canvas.height + 150){

        y2 = -car2.height;
        x2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 630);
        drawElapsedTime();
    }
};

//========================
//All game draw properties
//========================

function gameStart(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawCar();
    drawCar2();
    drawMultiple();
    drawMultiple2();
    animate();
    drawElapsedTime();
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `x -= 0`? It does nothing. Also where are most of your variables defined? I think you need to include some more code.

Comment: Collision detection requires knowing the shape of the objects, and all relevant dimensions and requires comparisons in at least two dimensions to detect intersection.  I only see you comparing height, nothing else.

Comment: You've posted code that doesn't work. The code does whatever it does. Some questions in this style get results because answerers can tell what the author intended, and how it deviates from what the code does. This question is not very clear about that, so it's a harder one to answer. To the asker: the code doesn't work because it doesn't detect car collision. In fact, it's not even clear that it tries to. I think you should make an argument of why it should work. The `addEventListener` stuff looks fine though.

Comment: sorry about that, i edited it and put the rest of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on shape and direction.

If they are both boxes then you need the top, bottom, left and right edges. You can get this with two corner points.

*Disclaimer:(May need some debugging [untested])

```
In Array:
0 = Top left X
1 = Top left Y
2 = Bottom right X
3 = Bottom right Y
```

----------Start

```
var Car1 = [100, 100, 200, 200];
var Car2 = [150, 150, 250, 250];

// Will return hit result relative to first box
function isHit(obj1, obj2)
{
    var hitOnLeft = (obj1[0] <= obj2[2]) && ((obj1[1] <= obj2[3]) || (obj1[2] >= obj2[1]));
    var hitOnRight = (obj1[2] >= obj2[0]) && ((obj1[1] <= obj2[3]) || (obj1[2] >= obj2[1]));

    return hitOnLeft || hitOnRight;
}

document.write(isHit(Car1, Car2));
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i dont know how to debug this code. I put it in komodo edit and it is giving me an error

Comment: Will this work for uploaded images (sprites) that are rectangular?

Comment: yes it will as the data about the hit areas are independent from the image itself.  you could use the image size and location as the data or provide offsets as needed.